# cannot resolve one-to-many relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I try to understand coredata. What goes well is adding a Hond and the gewicht. That is neatly put the gewicht in the relationship. But the moment I want to add a extra gewicht later, I run into a problem that I can not do that.

I get to see the following message:

> NSManagedObject' is not convertible to 'Hond'

[image: My enitys]

**This is my code in which I try to add a weight**

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let hondEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Hond", in: context)!
        let hond = NSManagedObject(entity: hondEntity, insertInto: context)

        let gewichtHondEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "GewichtHond", in: context)!
        let gewichtHond = NSManagedObject(entity: gewichtHondEntity, insertInto: context)

        let nieuwGewicht = GewichtHond(context: context)
        nieuwGewicht.datum = Date()
        nieuwGewicht.gewicht = Double("38")!
        //gewichtHond.setValue(Date(), forKey: "datum")
        //gewichtHond.setValue(Double("38"), forKey: "gewicht")
        Hond.addToGewichten(gewichtHond) //NSManagedObject' is not convertible to 'Hond

        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Saved")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

**My Hond+CoreDataProperties.swift**

```
    extension Hond {

        @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Hond> {
            return NSFetchRequest<Hond>(entityName: "Hond")
        }

        @NSManaged public var chipnummer: Int64
        @NSManaged public var dierenarts: String?
        @NSManaged public var geboortedatum: Date
        @NSManaged public var geslacht: Int16
        @NSManaged public var hondId: String?
        @NSManaged public var kleur: String?
        @NSManaged public var naam: String?
        @NSManaged public var orderID: Int16
        @NSManaged public var plaatsVanChip: String?
        @NSManaged public var telefoonnummerDierenarts: String?
        @NSManaged public var vachttype: String?
        @NSManaged public var gewichten: Set<GewichtHond>

    }

    // MARK: Generated accessors for gewichten
    extension Hond {

        @objc(addGewichtenObject:)
        @NSManaged public func addToGewichten(_ value: GewichtHond)

        @objc(removeGewichtenObject:)
        @NSManaged public func removeFromGewichten(_ value: GewichtHond)
/*
       @objc(addGewichten:)
       @NSManaged public func addToGewichten(_ values: NSSet)

       @objc(removeGewichten:)
       @NSManaged public func removeFromGewichten(_ values: NSSet)
*/ 
    }
```

How do I manage to add an extra gewicht?

Comment: `hond1.setValue(hond1, forKey: "Hond")`: this is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading. Basically it says that the type of the `gewicht` relationship is a set rather than a number. This indicates also an interference with the `gewicht` attribute in `GewichtHond`.

To avoid the naming confusion it's highly recommended to name relationships with the entity name of the counterpart and a one-to-one relationship in singular form and a one-to-many relationship in plural form. The one-to-many relationship should be named as `gewichten`. The type in Swift is supposed to be `Set<GewichtHond>` not unspecified `NSSet`

To add and remove a `GewichtHond` instance to/from a set at least these two accessor methods are needed in the `Hond` subclass

```
// MARK: Generated accessors for gewichten
extension Hond {

    @objc(addGewichtenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToGewichten(_ value: GewichtHond)

    @objc(removeGewichtenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromGewichten(_ value: GewichtHond)

}
```

Now create a `Hond` instance and a `GewichtHond` instance and add the latter to the relationship set

```
let hond = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Hond", into: context) as! Hond
let gewichtHond = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "GewichtHond" , into: context) as! GewichtHond

hond.addToGewichten(gewichtHond)
```

Side note: In a `NSManagedObject` subclass dot notation `hond1.datum = Date()` is much more convenient (**and safer**) than KVC method `hond1.setValue(Date(), forKey: "datum")`.

Comment: Little bit off-topic, but I think still relevant: do you create `NSManagedObject` classes yourself to avoid non-generic `NSSet` and `NSOrderedSet`? I only just got the idea, last time I read it thinking why the additional work for yourself..

Comment: Yes, I do. I create the classes always with Menu Editor > Create NSManagedObject subclasses and then edit the classes manually to replace the `NS` types with native Swift types and remove the question marks for the (as many as possible) non-optional properties

Comment: Is it much work to maintain it manually? Do I get an error incase I forget one variable?

Comment: Of course manual work is more error-prone than automatic created stuff. But practically it's not so much work. The effort is quite low when you update the class right after changing the model afterwards.

Comment: I hope I have understood your answer correctly. However, I now get the following message and I do not know what goes wrong. I have updated my code in my question. The error I get in Xcode is: NSManagedObject' is not convertible to 'Hond'

Comment: I updated my answer using a more convenient API to insert an object. It should fix the error.

Comment: PS: and you have to write `hond.addToGewichten(gewichtHond)` (lowercase!)  like in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, too much thought in a box and therefore no further. I now have the problem that if a weight is added also new dog is added. The weight should be added to the existing dog. I also had this problem at my first post.

Comment: I was answering your primary question how to add an object to a relationship which is a `Set`. It's just an example. Of course you can create **one** dog and many weights and add them to this single dog. Uncomment the other two methods in the extension to add many items simultaneously. If you need to use an existing dog you have to `fetch` it from the database.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear enough in the first instance ... I'm going to come out now I know i first te `fetch` the existing dog.